# How to name table in EasyXLS?

Tags: vbscript

I have bought easyXLS Professional and I cant find out how to create a table to a worksheet - and give it a name... In Microsoft Excel it is possible to create a table and give it a name - by using ctrl+t.
See the screenshot here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak5nrcTR_zUIzG50tE9svzfhifxx

So I want to do the same in easyXLS - so I e.g. can set a theme for the specific table...

I have already tried all the different examples from the documentation - https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/features.html
 - in VBS.

And I have tried to find a relevant method in the API Docs but without any luck.

Does anyone know how to create a simple table in easyXLS and assign a name to it.?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only table with a name, that EasyXLS has, is the pivot table.

But you can create a simple table of data without a name and set autoformat for its formatting elements.

```
Set workbook = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument")

Set worksheet = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelWorksheet")
workbook.easy_addWorksheet(worksheet)

Set xlsTable = worksheet.easy_getExcelTable()

'define an autoformat for the table
Dim AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1
AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1 = 21
Dim xlsAutoFormat
Set xlsAutoFormat = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat")
xlsAutoFormat.InitAs(AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1)

'apply autoformat
xlsTable.easy_setRangeAutoFormat_2 "A1:F10", xlsAutoFormat

'export excel file
workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile ("C:\excel.xlsx")
```

This code use one of the [predefined autoformat for excel](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/excel-predefined-formatting.html), the full list of available predefined formats is [here](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/API_Documentation/EasyXLS/Constants/Styles.html).

If you don't like any of the predefined autoformats, you can define custom ones like:

```
'define an autoformat for the table
Dim AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1
AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1 = 21
Dim xlsAutoFormat
Set xlsAutoFormat = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat")
'xlsAutoFormat.InitAs(AUTOFORMAT_COLORFUL1)

'set the formatting style of the header
Dim xlsHeaderStyle
Set xlsHeaderStyle = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelStyle")
xlsHeaderStyle.setBackground(&hff90ee90)
xlsHeaderStyle.setFontSize(12)
xlsAutoFormat.setHeaderRowStyle(xlsHeaderStyle)

'...more formatting for the table elements
```

Moreover, if you would like to change between MS Excel themes, you can set a theme for the Excel document and set the autoformat colors using theme colors.

```
Dim THEME_COLORS_APEX
THEME_COLORS_APEX = "Apex"
workbook.setTheme_2(THEME_COLORS_APEX)

'define an autoformat for the table
Dim xlsAutoFormat
Set xlsAutoFormat = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat")

Dim xlsThemeColor
Set xlsThemeColor = CreateObject("EasyXLS.Themes.ThemeColor")
xlsThemeColor.setColor 4, 2

' Set the formatting style of the header
Dim xlsHeaderStyle
Set xlsHeaderStyle = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelStyle")
xlsHeaderStyle.setBackground_2(xlsThemeColor)
xlsHeaderStyle.setFontSize(12)
xlsAutoFormat.setHeaderRowStyle(xlsHeaderStyle)

'...more formatting for the table elements
```

There are a bunch of predefined themes and also you can create your own theme. More about [Excel themes](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/excel-theme.html).